# Trace all calls from a program?

Tags: c, linux, trace

A program is installed on 2 computers. A certain library is working correctly in one computer but not working at all in the other. I wonder if a library is missing.

I'm using strace so I can see which libraries are being called by the program at runtime. All libraries mentioned by strace are correct but does strace also detect if one library calls another library or file ? Any way to detect this scenario ?

Answer (score 5):

Yes strace will detect calls from loaded libraries.

If you want to trace library calls (not system ones), use [`ltrace`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/ltrace)

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you want to **view your app's function call graph**, i.e. which functions call one another, which library they live in, etc.  If so, you may want to check out the [callgrind tool](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/cl-manual.html) (which is part of valgrind).

Here is an example that uses [callgrind to profile some code](http://www.slac.stanford.edu/BFROOT/www/Computing/Optimization/genprof.html).

Once you've used callgrind to generate profile data for your app, load it into [Kcachegrind](http://kcachegrind.sourceforge.net/html/Home.html) to visualize it. It's simple point-and-click: highlight function, see callers/callees, view the call graph, and so on.  I've found it quite useful in similar circumstances.

Comment: The link to stanford is password protected :(.

Answer (score 0):

To check for libraries missing, run `ldd /full/path/to/program`

Answer (score 0):

For programs using `Clang` to compile, try get call trace of the programs with [`Xray`](https://llvm.org/docs/XRay.html). It heuristically instruments part of a program and has very low runtime overhead.